# How to get substring dynamically

Tags: javascript, mysql

How can I get `substring` dynamically, I want to split one word into two parts one is a string and other to no,

`AA112` this is my string so from sql query

```
SELECT substr(thisColumn, 1,2) AS String from thisTable
```

I am getting `AA` in the query the index(2) I am pasing is dynamic I am getting from some value, So here I am able to get the string now I want to get the number +1 like it is 112 then -> 113

I have tried several queries but it is not working, I have tried doing it with `javascript` substring but it didn't work out.

**Sample output**
`AAA123` -> `AAA` and `124`

`AA4` -> `AA` and `5`

`BBBB8` -> `BBBB` and `9`

Comment: Is the value fixed? Like the value length will it be always 5 characters long? and the first two characters will always be string while the last three will always be numerical?

Comment: @tcadidot0 No that is the issue the length is not fixed it can be `AAAAA12`, `AAA45` so I have to get the string and no, the string I am getting from above query, main thing I want to have no after that string +1

Comment: @manish, Give some different sample output.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve this in MySQL/MariaDB using `REGEXP_REPLACE`

Comment: @Kitta please check the edit

Comment: What MySQL version you're using?

Comment: @tcadidot0 I am using 5.5

Comment: Unfortunately @manishthakur , `REGEXP_REPLACE` is only available on 8+ .. that would be much easier to use ;)

Comment: Share me one example then I will try to update my db

Comment: Look at this fiddle for `REGEXP_REPLACE` example in MySQL 8.0 : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5epqZXQdMaLTdFge4iNS6D/0

Comment: There is a long way to do in v 5.5 but I have concern over it's performance on large tables. I will post the code in answer and you can try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const input="AA112";
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
const number = input.match(numberPattern)[0];
const text = input.replace(number,"");

console.log(text);   //AA
console.log(number); //112
 
const incremented = parseInt(number) + 1;
console.log(incremented);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `LOCATE`, `IF`,`LEAST` and `SUBSTRING` over two sub-query can achieve the output result you're looking for.

```
SELECT VAL, 
       SUBSTRING(VAL,1,FIRSTNUM-1),
       SUBSTRING(VAL,FIRSTNUM,999)+1 
FROM
(SELECT VAL,LEAST(V0+0,V1+0,V2+0,V3+0,V4+0,V5+0,V6+0,V7+0,V8+0,V9+0) FIRSTNUM FROM
(SELECT VAL,
       IF(LOCATE(0,VAL)=0,999,LOCATE(0,VAL)) V0,
       IF(LOCATE(1,VAL)=0,999,LOCATE(1,VAL)) V1,
       IF(LOCATE(2,VAL)=0,999,LOCATE(2,VAL)) V2,
       IF(LOCATE(3,VAL)=0,999,LOCATE(3,VAL)) V3,
       IF(LOCATE(4,VAL)=0,999,LOCATE(4,VAL)) V4,
       IF(LOCATE(5,VAL)=0,999,LOCATE(5,VAL)) V5,
       IF(LOCATE(6,VAL)=0,999,LOCATE(6,VAL)) V6,
       IF(LOCATE(7,VAL)=0,999,LOCATE(7,VAL)) V7,
       IF(LOCATE(8,VAL)=0,999,LOCATE(8,VAL)) V8,
       IF(LOCATE(9,VAL)=0,999,LOCATE(9,VAL)) V9 FROM mytable) A ) B;
```

Here I use `LOCATE` to find the location of the number occurrence in the value then `REPLACE` to change the value to 999 if it returns 0. This is essential for the next operation using `LEAST` because if I leave it 0, it'll return all 0 instead. The reason I use `LEAST` is because if you look at the 4th data example in the fiddle it's `AAAAA321`. This will return the result in grid like the following:

```
+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   VAL    | V0  | V1  | V2  | V3  | V4  | V5  | V6  | V7  | V8  | V9  |
+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| AAA123   | 999 |   4 |   5 |   6 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 |
| AA4      | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 |   3 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 |
| BBBB8    | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 |   5 | 999 |
| AAAAA321 | 999 |   8 |   7 |   6 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 | <---this
| AAA45    | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 |   4 |   5 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 |
+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

The first number occurrence is actually '3' but because I construct the query running from 0-9, I'll always get the first number in front (in this case '1' is the 8th occurrence) despite it being on the middle or last position. That's why `LEAST` will correctly take which number is actually located first using `LOCATE` function.

In the last outer query, I use the result from the `LEAST` function (assigned as `FIRSTNUM`) as the defining value for the `SUBSTRING`. The first substring I use it as the end location subtract by 1 to get the strings and in the second substring I use it as the first location to get the number (I end the location with 999).

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/F15cxiYJxGcozYUbQukeB/5

Edit: I realized I cannot use `REPLACE` because if the location is like `10`, it will replace `0` to `999` which makes it become `1999` instead. So I use `IF`.